Accessing SQL Server RDS fails with
I have a .NET 8, C# lambda function. I need it to access a SQL Server RDS instance.
In my .csproj file I have:
<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>

And the lambda process dies with:

Process terminated. Couldn't find a valid ICU package installed on the system. Please install libicu (or icu-libs) using your package manager and try again. Alternatively you can set the configuration flag System.Globalization.Invariant to true if you want to run with no globalization support. Please see https://aka.ms/dotnet-missing-libicu for more information.

So I then change to
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>

and the function starts, but then the SQL client aborts with:

"message": "Unable to open database (5),
Data Source=??.??.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com;
Initial Catalog=??;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=??;Trust Server Certificate=True;Application Name=??",
"exception": {
"type": "System.NotSupportedException",
"message": "Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported.",
"source": "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient",

From what I read, SqlClient wants "false", but .NET 8 wants "true".
Does anyone know the magic to get this working?

Sounds familiar, Globalization Invariant Mode is not supported #220. Do you have any control over the runtime container that's hosting the Lambda function? Can you install the necessary ICU libraries and set the environment variable DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false?

I found a solution that seems to work.  I added an ItemGroup for linux-x64 pointing to the latest ICU library I found on NuGet.  Interestingly enough I did not need to explicitly install it via NuGet.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>13.0.0</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>2023.99.99</AssemblyVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AWSProjectType>Lambda</AWSProjectType>
    <AssemblyName>bootstrap</AssemblyName>
    <!-- This property makes the build directory similar to a publish directory and helps the AWS .NET Lambda Mock Test Tool find project dependencies. -->
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
<!-- If TRUE Sql Client aborts -->
    <InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
     <!-- Generate ready to run images during publishing to improve cold start time. -->
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-x64'">
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="72.1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="72.1.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup> 
 <ItemGroup>

From the original sample Lambda code I had found last year (forget where, now), there was a comment in the .CSProj file
  <!-- 
  When publishing Lambda functions for ARM64 to the provided.al2 runtime a newer version of libicu needs to be included
  in the deployment bundle because .NET requires a newer version of libicu then is preinstalled with Amazon Linux 2.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RuntimeIdentifier)' == 'linux-arm64'">
    <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.AppLocalIcu" Value="68.2.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ICU.ICU4C.Runtime" Version="68.2.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>

I'm using the al2023 runtime and not ARM but this was a good clue.
